# How to find which C function is calling a particular TCL proc?

Tags: c, linux, tcl, stack-trace

I have a code base which have C and TCL and C functions calls tcl procs repeatedly.

I want to debug the code and for it I need to know which C function is calling a particular TCL proc.

I tried this :   [TCL stack trace](http://wiki.tcl.tk/16183)

but it gives stack trace for TCL part only. Is it possible to find out stack trace for C code also from within TCL proc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about running the code in a debugger, setting the breakpoint at `Tcl_Eval()` (or whatever method your C code uses to call out into Tcl) then make your program call that piece of Tcl code and then examine the stack?

You'd need the debug build of your C code (with symbols); debugging version of the Tcl runtime would also make the stack trace more comprehensible.

FWIW, I failed to find any published API for traversing the stack trace [here](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/contents.htm), so presumably it does not exist.  Moreover, to traverse the stack on the C side, the Tcl runtime would need something like [`libunwind`](http://www.nongnu.org/libunwind/), and AFAIK Tcl does not have anything like this built-in.

Comment: You might be able to do something with clever use of breakpoints and logging in gdb…

Comment: @DonalFellows, `windbg` on Windows should work just as well for this task.  We do not know the OP's platform though.

Comment: The code base I am working on have multiple Tcl_Eval calls and the way the code-base is complied in such a way that the code which calls TCL proc cannot be debugged. Although I can make changes to the code but I cannot change the make files.

Comment: @nav_jan, then there's not much that you can do: C in your case compiles down to machine codes and there's no "stack info" kept anywhere: the debugger just uses the platform's ABI conventions to walk up the functions' stack frames and correlates their addresses with the symbol table which is present in unstripped binaries. So, I'd say: start with getting the stack trace in GDB and then try to correlate what you see with the symbol table dumped by `nm` or `readelf` or `objdump` etc; but better yet try lobbying some cooperation with the C-side folks to get a debug build of their code.